# Input field mapped dynamically but failed to get input values from all the fields React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 4-5 input fields mapped as per response. The user needs to enter value in each field but when I try to fetch the final value from all fields it gives me value of only the last input field. I would like to have values in an array which I can later join. There's one handler function for onChange.
I have tried using spread operator but doesn't help.

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({});
const handleChange = (value,name,i)=>{
 setInputValue({ ...inputValue, [name]: value })
}

records.map((record, i) => {
              return (
                <>
                    <input
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        handleChange(e.target.value, e.target.name, i)
                      }
                      name={record.title}
                      key={i}
                      value={record.value}
                 
                    />
                  </label>
                </>
              );
            })
```

Comment: You might want to show some code for us to take a look at. Otherwise we won‘t be able to help…

Comment: It's nearly impossible to answer without looking at the code you have written. Please add the relevant code

Comment: @GabeRAMturn added some code.

Comment: Your `input` does not have a name.

Comment: It does have a name

Answer (score 1):

You can use built in Form tag for that matter:

```
<form onSubmit={submitHandlerFunction}>
 {fields.map(field => (
  <input key={field.name} name={field.name}/>
  )}
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not the correct requirement. I don't need to submit the form. I just have to get the values from the field in an array and render it on the ui. This is an incorrect solution